# Why does this palindrome function fail?

Tags: python

Apparently, it should be `return is_palindrome(middle(word))` at the end in place of the last two lines. But why? Shouldn't the function stop after `return True`?

```
def first(word):
    return word[0]

def last(word):
    return word[-1]

def middle(word):
    return word[1:-1]

def is_palindrome(word):
    #base case
    if len(word) <= 1:
        return True
    if first(word) != last(word):
        return False
    else:
        is_palindrome(middle(word))
```

Comment: You want to `return` the result of `is_palindrome(middle(word))`.

Comment: Currently in the last line you are calling `is_palindrome(...)` and ignoring the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return True` only returns from the single instance of the function that it is called from. Since this is a recursive function, you're going to end up with a stack of instances of the function looking something like this:

```
is_palindrome('abcdcba')
  is_palindrome('bcdcb')
    is_palindrome('cdc')
      is_palindrome('d')
```

The recursion finally reaches its base case in the last one (string length of 1) and returns `True`. The problem is, it only returns to the `is_palindrome('cdc')` instance. From there, since you've not told your function to do anything with the result, it only returns `None` to the next instance back. Similarly, that `None` gets propagated back through the stack and to your initial function call. That's not terribly useful.

```
    ^ None ^
is_palindrome('abcdcba')
      ^ None ^
  is_palindrome('bcdcb')
        ^ None ^
    is_palindrome('cdc')
          ^ True ^
      is_palindrome('d')
```

When you `return` the result of the recursive call instead, then that causes *each* instance of the function to take what the *next* instance returns, and passes it back to the *previous* instance, all the way to the original call. In other words, it creates a chain that allows the final result to propagate all the way back to the user.

```
    ^ True ^
is_palindrome('abcdcba')
      ^ True ^
  is_palindrome('bcdcb')
        ^ True ^
    is_palindrome('cdc')
          ^ True ^
      is_palindrome('d')
```

Comment: Yes, yes, I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
def first(word):
 return word[0]

def last(word):
 return word[-1]

def middle(word):
 return word[1:-1]

def is_palindrome(word):
 #base case
 if len(word) <= 1:
     return True
 if first(word) != last(word):
     return False
 else:
     return is_palindrome(middle(word))

print(is_palindrome("racecar"))
```

The reason being, that you are returning boolean values from your function is_palindrome's if conditions. Therefore, when you recursively apply it, your base case is exiting with a true/false value. You need to return that  value when you make a recursion call in the else condition. That is how the recursion tree will keep the required boolean values stored throughout the depth of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Make a small adjustment to your version to better understand what's happening:

```
def first(word):
    return word[0]

def last(word):
    return word[-1]

def middle(word):
    return word[1:-1]

def is_palindrome(word):
    #base case
    if len(word) <= 1:
        print(1)
        return True
    if first(word) != last(word):
        print(2)
        return False
    else:
        print(3)
        is_palindrome(middle(word))
```

Now running `is_palindrome('abcba')` will print

```
3
3
1
```

as I think you expected from your recursive approach except there is no `True` at the end of the output. You see that first you called `is_palindrome('abcba')`, then `is_palindrome('bcb')`, then `is_palindrome('c')`. The last one of these calls returns `True` to the second one, the second one returns `None` to the first one and the first one eventually returns `None` as you can see with `is_palindrome('abcba') is None`. This is why the `return` statement in front of the last line is needed as mentioned before: it matters what the original call will return, so even though `return True` is reached at some point, this is not the output of your code.

I hope this helped.

PS: Checking if a string is palindrome is much easier: just check if `word == word[::-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def first(word):
    return word[0]

def last(word):
    return word[-1]

def middle(word):
    return word[1:-1]

def is_palindrome(word):
    #base case
    if len(word) <= 1:
        return True
    elif first(word) != last(word):
        return False
    else:
        return is_palindrome(middle(word))
```

Here the the code is working like recursion the function is_palindrome is returning true or false but you are not utilising it.Ex

```
is_palindrome('ana')
 is_palindrome('n')
  return True
 return True
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Rawing already fixed your problem by adding 'return'.
Regarding your 'still don't understand how it works' comment: it's a recursive function. At first, recursion can be difficult to understand. It may help if you think of this as not one call, but as a whole stack of them, with only the last one returning true or false.
Also, you can leave out the 'else:'.

Comment: Thanks. I have deleted my comment before you posted, as I understood about else :)